# How to connect to two different Windows VPNs in same router

Tags: vpn, windows-10

Two windows computers are connected to Inteno router.
Both servers accept Windows VPN incoming connections in 1723 port.

Windows 10 client needs to connect into both of those servers.

TCP Port 2000 in router is redirected to 1723 port in server 1
TCP Port 2001 in router is redirected to 1723 port in server 2

In Windows 10 client port numbers are added after server name:

myserver.com:2000
myserver.com:2001

Trying to connect to server causes error Remote name does not resolve.

According to [Windows VPN client connect on different port](https://serverfault.com/questions/120644/windows-vpn-client-connect-on-different-port) it is not possible to specify diffrent TCP ports in widnows 10 VPN client.

If TCP Port 1723 in router is redirected to 1723 port in server, it works. however this allows to use only one server VPN.

How to create two differentVPN clients in windows 10 in single computer so that it is possible to connect to different server VPNs ?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of the linked question, with multiple **not possible** answers with better and worse explanations. The problem is not the port 1723 but the GRE protocol.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows VPN client connect on different port](https://serverfault.com/questions/120644/windows-vpn-client-connect-on-different-port)